# Why is my variable not be included in my subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm simply trying to pass along a variable to my shell script, but it isn't being handed off.  I've 
following examples from the python docs, but it's not working.  What am I missing?

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh' + variable] , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Are you definitely supposed to be using a list there, and not a string?

Comment: @Totem, both will work; with `shell=True`, the first element of the list is passed to the shell as the script to run, and any other elements are passed to the shell as additional arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add space after *./script.sh*:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh ' + variable] , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Yeah, I misparsed it in my head. I confused this case (list with one string argument) with the actual mistake (list with two string arguments).

Comment: @nonlinearmind, ...mind you the caveats around "worked". It worked if the variable has no spaces in it, has no glob characters, has no shell syntax...

Comment: This really isn't a good idea; if you want to pass a string as a shell command line, pass it as a string, not as a list with that string as its only element.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `shell=True` here at all, unless you want any actual shell syntax in your variable (like `>file.log`) to be executed.

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh', variable],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

---

If you *really* want `shell=True`, you have a few options to do so securely. The first is to use `pipes.quote()` (or, in Python 3, `shlex.quote()`) to prevent shell escapes:

```
subprocess.Popen('./script.sh ' + pipes.quote(variable), shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The second is to pass the name as a subsequent argument (note the empty string, which becomes `$0` in the generated shell):

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh "$1"', '', variable], shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

---

Remember, [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) isn't just for SQL -- his younger sister 
`Susan $(rm -rf /)` is out there too.

Comment: And don't forget their cousin `"Barry", __import__(os).system("rm -rf /")`, who loves `eval` as much as Susan loves `Popen`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're combining two different ways to doing things. And, on top of that, you're doing it wrong, but just fixing the "doing it wrong" isn't the answer.

You can put your two arguments in a list, and then launch it without the shell, like `['./script.sh', variable]`. This is usually better. Using the shell means you have to deal with quoting, and with accidental or malicious injection, and can interfere with your input and output, and adds a performance cost. So, if you don't need it, don't use it.

Or you can put your two arguments in a string, and then launch it with the shell, like `'./script.sh ' + variable`.

But you can't put your two arguments in a string, and then put that string in a list. In some cases, it will happen to work, but that's not something you can rely on.

In some cases, you can use a list with the shell,* or a string without the shell,** but generally you shouldn't do that unless you know what you're doing, and in any case, you still shouldn't be using a list of one string unless there's a specific reason you need to.***

---

If you want to use a list of arguments, do this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh', variable], shell=False, …)
```

Notice that this is a list of two strings, not a list of one joined-up string, and that `shell=False`.

---

If you want to use a shell command line, don't put the command line in a list, don't skip the space between the arguments, and quote any non-static arguments, like this:

```
subprocess.Popen('./script.sh ' + shlex.quote(variable), shell=True, …)
```

---

<sub>* Using a list with the shell on Windows is never useful; they just get combined up in some unspecified way. But on Unix, `subprocess` will effectively prepend `'/bin/sh'` and `'-c'` to your list, and use that as the arg list for `/bin/sh`, which can be simpler than trying to quote shell arguments, and at least arguably more concise than explicitly calling `/bin/sh` with `shell=False`.</sub>

<sub>** Using a string without the shell on Unix is never useful; that just tries to find a program whose name is the whole string, which is going to fail (unless you're really unlucky). But on Windows, it can be useful; `subprocess` tries to combine your arguments into a string to be passed to `CreateProcess` in such a way that MSVCRT will parse them back to the same list of arguments on the other side, and in some edge cases it's necessary to create that string yourself.</sub>

<sub>*** Basically, you want to spawn `['/bin/sh', '-c', <command line>]` exactly.</sub>

Comment: The behavior is *not* unspecified -- `subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True)` is equivalent to `subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c'] + arg_list, shell=False)`. Thus, the first argument _is_ always used as the script to run (and subsequent arguments are *not* joined into a string).

Comment: ...it's possible to take deliberate advantage of this by referring to the argument vector (`"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc) inside of the script passed as the first list element.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: OK, I've rewritten the footnotes to make it more accurate. Better?

Comment: Better indeed. ("Yep" is apparently too short to be a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Would just add a space after script name:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh ' + variable], shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the security issues, though; the variable can be modified by the shell before it gets to the subprocess, or can contain instructions that tell the shell to run a completely different command entirely.